# Function / criteria to give me records from the last 90 minutes

Tags: sql, ms-access, datetime

I have a time/date field in my select query and I want to set the criteria to only return records from the last 90 minutes. What criteria should I use?

Comment: table and columns please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use the [DateDiff](http://www.databasedev.co.uk/ms_access_date_functions.html) function to do the comparison.  Something like:

```
... WHERE DateDiff("n", RecordDate, CurrentDate) <= 90 ...
```

Comment: please giv e me exact criteira to copy and paste into design view. I do not know SQL

Comment: No, I won't (can't with the limited information you've provided, not even including table design or column names) implement your application for you.  I'm also not familiar with MS Acces design view or any of that.  Note that copying/pasting code into your application is a dangerous practice.  You'll have a much easier time supporting your application if you understand and implement your own code.  If you're working in database development, learning a little SQL is a very good idea.